# Netbeans IDE can use Grails Framework? Or Eclipse?

Tags: grails

I would like to know about Grails Framework. When I search grails tool suite to download,i just can find 'Based on Eclipse'. Is there anything for Netbeans IDE? Can I use Grails framework on Netbeans IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use NetBeans 6.5 or above versions which support Groovy/ Grails development. NetBeans comes with a Groovy editor with various integrated tools and offers features like code completion, providing name of dynamic methods for grails domain and controller class. It is light and offers great functional features.

Check this link

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#ide

Also you can take help from book **Grails in Action** to know more about Grails framework and how to develop applications using it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA is the best IDEA for Grails and it blows all other IDEs out of the water. Although you have to pay $199 for the license, it is definitely worth the $$$.

If you are a student you can get the Academic license for free :).